# (SOLVED) Cannot login in recovery mode

Tags: release-loki, boot

after updates from 2017-10-16...
[image]

...my system won't boot anymore with following errors...
[image]

I tried to boot into recovery mode, but after typing my username the system does not prompt for password...
[image]

...it simply returns to login prompt again
[image]

Is there any other way to rescue the system from complete re-installation in this hopeless case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solution found!

1. Boot from Live USB
2. `mkdir /mnt/recover` (create a temp folder)
3. `mount /dev/sdc1 /mnt/recover` (mount my root fs to temp folder)
4. Tried `chroot /mnt/recover` (to become root of my mounted root fs) but received an error that there is no bin/bash folder
5. Copied the bin folder from Live USB to my `/mnt/recover`
6. `chroot /mnt/recover` finally did work
7. `sudo apt purge lightdm` (to remove the faulty lightdm packages)
8. `sudo apt install lightdm` (to install lightdm anew, but received an error that repos couldn't be reached)
9. Restarted the machine and booted to my system, without lightdm it booted in text mode. But I was finally able to log in normally!
10. From here simple `sudo apt install lightdm` did install the display manager.
11. Reboot, and my system is back!
    [image]

Comment: My question is how did you even write a command in the first place, if you couldn't even log in in console mode?!

Comment: By using a LIVE USB.